# How to scroll two panes in sync in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In my scenario I have two panes side by side: `(pane 1) | (pane 2)` and I want to scroll in both of them in sync, how can that be achieved?

I have tried setting `synchronize-panes` which will sync normal keystrokes like text input to the panes, but scrolling which I do with `prefix+[` followed by `PgUp`/`ctrl-y` does not get synchronized. In fact as soon as I do `prefix+[` the synchronization seems to go off until I exit scroll mode. Is there some way to keep sync in scroll mode?

I'm using tmux version 2.6

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with tmux, but this sort of worked for me: in your `~/.tmuxrc` set the bindings:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode C-y send-keys -t.- -X scroll-up\; send-keys -X scroll-up
bind-key -T copy-mode C-e send-keys -t.- -X scroll-down\; send-keys -X scroll-down
```

Then when both panes are in copy-mode (scroll mode), when you type `C-y` in one, it gives the scroll-up command to that pane, and again to the other one (`-t.-`). I don't have a PageUp key to try, but I think you can repeat these bindings replacing `C-y` by `PageUp`. For testing, I also added a binding for `control-s` to enter copy-mode in both panes:

```
bind-key -n C-S copy-mode\; copy-mode -t.-
```

so typing control-s enters copy-mode on both panes. However, I couldn't make a similar binding leave copy-mode:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode C-s send-keys -t.- -X cancel\;send-keys -X cancel
```